# Select2 work in modal Bootstrap. But i have a modal Bootstrap with other id

Tags: php, select, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I am using `Select2` library. 
But, I have a other Modal Bootstrap with modal id like:

```
<div id="EditData<?php echo $r['id_bahan']; ?>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    <form action="update-bahan?id=<?php echo $erow['id_bahan']; ?>" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group">
    <label>Satuan Bahan <font color = "f13c3c">*</font></label>
        <select  class="selectReason2" name="sattxt1" style="width: 100%" required>
            <option value="1">Amerika</option>
            <option value="2">Inggris</option>
            <option value="3">China</option>
            <option value="4">Mesir</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

---

and I've tried in various ways like :

**My Javascript** :

```
$(".selectReason").select2({dropdownParent: $('#EditData<?php echo $r['id_bahan']; ?> .modal-content'),width:'100%'})
```

and

```
$(".selectReason").select2({dropdownParent: $('#EditData .modal-content'),width:'100%'})
```

but still the search with select2 does not work well in Modal Bootstrap.
Help :(

Comment: I think the problem here - $('#EditData<?php echo $r['id_bahan']; ?> .modal-content'),width:'100%'}) . You can't run php code in javascript file.

Comment: i think so.
but I already lost the code <?php echo $r['id_bahan']; ?>,  and it's still the same